# Factorization of an unbounded operator as composition of a bounded operator composed with one whose inverse is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Does every densely-defined unbounded operator $P$ have a ``factorization'' of the form $$P = A B^{-1},$$
with $A$ and $B$ bounded?

Given two bounded operators $A,B$ such that $B^{-1}$ is a densely-defined unbounded operator, then clearly the composition $P:=AB^{-1}$ is a densely-defined (possibly) unbounded operator (may end up being bounded depending on the relationship between $A$ and $B$). My question is the converse of that.

An answer in either the Hilbert or Banach space setting would be appreciated. Also, additional assumptions on $P$ (like being closed) would be reasonable.

This question is related to factorization of ``transfer functions'' from control theory.

Comment: On the Hilbert space if $P$ is self-adjoint and positive then $A=P/(I+P)$ and $B=I/(I+P)$ should be fine. In general sort of polar decomposition could be helpful. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition

Comment: Your definitions imply that $AB^{-1}$ is closed. Is every such $P$ closed?